# Acumatica REST API Endpoint Action Call fails

Tags: rest, api, action, acumatica, endpoint

** NOTE: Any StackOverflow question that is critical of Acumatica will get down-voted.

I am trying to get a REST Web-Service-Endpoint Action working.

Extending the Default endpoint, I added an Action CreateShipmentAction.

```
URL: .../17.200.001/SalesOrder/CreateShipmentAction
SEND: {'entity':{'OrderNbr':{'value':'ME050225'},'OrderType':{'value':'SO'}},'parameters':{'value':null}}
METHOD: post
```

[image]

and this works fine.

Following the same procedure, I added CancelPurchaseOrderAction to Purchase Order.

```
URL: .../17.200.001/PurchaseOrder/CancelPurchaseOrderAction
SEND: {'entity':{'OrderNbr':{'value':'ME006802'},'OrderType':{'value':'DP'}},'parameters':{'value':null}}
METHOD: post
```

[image]

fails with "The Cancel Order button is disabled". Manually checking the PurchaseOrder, the Cancel-Order button is active via the website.

If I change the 'entity' OrderNbr to

```
SEND: {'entity':{'OrderNbr':{'value':'xxxME006802'},'OrderType':{'value':'DP'}},'parameters':{'value':null}}
```

which shouldn't match anything, I get the same error. It's like my 'entity' for the PurchaseOrder is not formatted correctly.

I would look up the necessary formatting for the 'entity' of PurchaseOrder in the Acumatica documentation, but I can't find any documentation. The VIEW_ENDPOINT_SERVICE documents do not spell this out either, which I think they should (else why have an API if the parameters are not defined...)

Comment: Could you show us how you define both action in the endpoint by adding their definition as images?

Comment: Definition images added. Adding the Actions was done very simply. These are defined under the appropriate endpoint Action area (SalesOrder, PurchaseOrder). If I can guess the correct entity data fields, I can get other endpoint actions to work (both Default and added). Just not PurchaseOrder. Version 2018R1.

Comment: The only difference I can note is that the SalesOrder already had Actions defined. I just added some. The PurchaseOrder had no Actions, so the ones I created were the 1st.

Comment: > Any StackOverflow question that is critical of Acumatica will get down-voted
- Your question appear complete and well put together, don't let that voting system affect your workflow if you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is inconsistency in Acumatica fields.

While the website URL for a PurchaseOrder has

```
?ScreenId=PO301000&OrderType=DP&OrderNbr=ME006802
```

Making one think the 'entity' fields for a REST Action API call would be

```
{OrderNbr:{value:"ME006802"},OrderType:{value:"DP"}}
```

It's actually (note the OrderType is now just Type with a different value)

```
{OrderNbr:{value:"ME006802"},Type:{value:"Drop Ship"}}
```

Programming to Acumatica's REST API is like Whack-A-Mole.... randomly try different things (since there is no documentation) and hopefully one may just luckily work....

Comment: It is "Type" because it is set as "Type" in the PurchaseOrder->Fields tab. You can extend endpoint and entity and add that field with any name you want.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov you are correct. That was how I finally solved it. How should I have determined that this Field, among the 16 shown, was required in the 'entity' definition for this Action? Hopefully I just don't know where the right documentation is.

Comment: Order Type and Order Nbr are key fields of the Purchase Order record and they are required for any action, as without knowing both of them you can't for sure identify the Purchase Order record.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov how would a programmer who is new to Acumatica know that the Order-Type (just "Type" in PurchaseOrder->Fields) and Order-Number are the key fields? In my Acumatica, Order-Number's are unique no matter the Order-Type, so one would assume that Order-Type is not a key, but it is. Only a programmer who knows the inner working of the database record's structure would know that the Order-Type is a key. Is there a list of record keys in the documentation?

Comment: If you have customizer role in Acumatica you can Ctrl+Alt + Click on Order Number field for example with and select View Data Class Source from Actions in the appeared modal. In the newer versions of Acumatica, there is a region called Keys which shows key fields. In the old versions, you can go through regions and look of IsKey = true

Comment: All this information about key fields and other things are covered in T100, T200 and T300 training courses for Application Developers.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Thanks. It looks like the 'Keys' region in the newer versions would have avoided this for me (2018R1). I must not have been the only one to have an issue with this. Having to Ctrl+Alt+Click on every Field to find the keys is very cumbersome on those with 50+ Fields.

Comment: The Endpoint-Service OpenApi swagger.json should probably have defined the 'entity' key fields that are required.

Comment: When I "put" to the /Bill Endpoint with 'entity':{'ReferenceNbr':{'value':'ME010704'},'Type':{'value':'Bill'}} I get "SuppliedByVendorID cannot be empty". I can't find this field in the Default Endpoint Fields for Bill. I can't find it's requirement using @SamvelPetrosov methodology either....

Answer (score 1):

One thing for sure is that when dealing with Acumatica Web Service, you need to work with the screen in the browser as well.

The Web Service can only do the same thing that are possible to do on the screen.

So if you go to the Purchase Order Screen and look at the record is the Cancel Order button enabled?

I notice something when I was testing this is that for the Sales Order and the Purchase Order, the same steps will not enable both actions. At least with the default settings one is getting when using the Sales Demo Data provided with the installer.

For the Sales Order, the record only need to not be "On Hold" in order for the action Create Shipment to be enabled.

Though for the Purchase Order, you not only need to not be "On Hold", you also need to have used the Approve action before the Cancel button gets enabled.

If I were to use the Cancel Order action before these were done, I was getting the same error as you are noting in your question but once these steps were done I was able to Cancel the Order properly.

The Request that I used were to following

- Sales Order

```
.../entity/DefaultPlus/17.200.001/SalesOrder/CreateShipmentAction
{
    "entity":
    {
        "OrderType":{"value":"SO"},
        "OrderNbr":{"value":"SO004264"}
    },
    "parameters":
    {
        "ShipmentDate":{"value":"06/05/2019"},
        "WarehouseID":{"value":"RETAIL"}
    }
}
```

- Purchase Order

```
.../entity/DefaultPlus/17.200.001/PurchaseOrder/CancelPurchaseOrderAction
{
    "entity":
    {
        "Type":{"value":"Normal"},
        "OrderNbr":{"value":"PO000701"}
    }
}
```

Comment: You are very correct. The issue is that if the 'entity' does not exist, Acumatica responds with "button not enabled" instead of 'entity not found', making the programmer think there was something wrong with the state of the object as you explained in this answer.

Comment: In the case of executing an action, if the entity is not found it will just try to execute the action on a blank record as if you had just clicked the new button.